# Modifying Google Custom search results with custom code

Tags: javascript, google-search

I have a Google custom search engine installed on my website. I want to modify the search results. I know that it could harm the ToS.

So, firstly, I want to delete some string from every search resul. Here is the function I wrote earlier:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval("pakeisti()",100)
function pakeisti()
  {
    elem = document.getElementById("searchas");
    y = elem.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i=0; i< y.length; i++)
     {
          str = y[i].className;
      if (str.search("gs-title") != 0 ) {
        var newHTML = y[i].innerHtml;
        newHTML = newHTML.replace('STRING - ',' k');
        newHTML = newHTML.replace('<a','<p');
        newHTML = newHTML.replace('</a>','</p>');
        y[i].innerHtml = newHTML; }
     }
  }
</script>
```

Earlier this script worked, but now it gives me error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

That error is occurring because `y[i].innerHtml` is undefined.

To avoid the problem, change the `if` statement to this:

```
if (str.search("gs-title") != 0 && y[i].innerHtml != null) {
```

You are probably experiencing this because you're using `String.search()` incorrectly in your `if` statement. If the search string does not appear in the target string, `.search()` will return `-1`, not 0. (A response of 0 means that the string appears at the first character in the target.) So you probably meant:

```
if (str.search("gs-title") != -1 ...
```